# I want to remove index.php from codeigniter url

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to remove index.php from codeigniter url 
my current configurations I tried so far with zero results are

folder structure:
xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\controllers\olx\olx.php
xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\views\olx\frmSignup

my HTACCESS file on the location
xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter.HTACCESS with the following contents nothing else in .HTACCESS file for me

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /olx
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

mod_rewrite is enabled checked using phpinfo();

following changes made to config.php file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mypc/olx';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

when try to access this url

```
http://mypc/codeigniter/olx/frmSignup i get 404 error
```

changes made to routes.php are

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'olx';
$route['olx/frmSignup']  = 'olx/frmSignup';
```

please help I want to access my app without index.php. i am working on localhost with Windows7

Answer (score 1):

Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in my virtual host file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf in ubuntu
Change AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All in my virtual host file at /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf in windows

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All    <---- replace None with All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All   <---  replace None with All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
....
```

Then put this code in .htaccess file in root folder in codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

It will definately work.

Answer (score 0):

From http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/urls.html - Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Codeigniter

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

so not olx as it's a controller and not a folder

in config

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

in route

```
$route['default_controller'] = "olx";
```

and move your 
     D:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\controllers\olx\olx.php
to 
      D:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\controllers\olx.php

and olx should look like

```
class olx extends CI_Controller {


 public function __construct()
   {
       parent::__construct();

 }


public function index()
{

    echo "test";
    // or $this->load->view('olx/overview.php', $data);

}

}
```

and try localhost/codeigniter/ or localhost/codeigniter/olx

Comment: I tried your .htaccess file and tried to access the following url with   same 404 result

http://localhost/olx/frmSignup

Comment: what is your localhost, how do access a html file in that directory? think the url is the problem and the config as those are different now, not the htaccess.

Comment: http://localhost/codeigniter/test.html further if its developed in CI files will be placed in controller and views directory respectivly and than index.php will be involved in the url I want to access the files placed in views folder like this http://localhost/olx/frmSignup

Comment: I tried ur updated suggestion but still getting 404 let me tell u my exact folder structure again
Codeigniter\application\controller\olx\olx.php
Codeigniter\application\views\olx\frmSignup.php and for ur information frmSignup is view not controller. I have applied all the settings u mentioned but no result

Comment: steps: 1/ know where your localhost is directed to with xampp (use an index.html) 2/ copy the index.html to a folder named olx and check if you can access the html with localhost/olx  3) copy codedigniter there and use an echo in your controller to test. the folder application  and index.php should be in your olx folder  (not olx/codeigniter/application)

Comment: actually i've tested with test.html and placed it in D:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\test.html and accessible via http://localhost/codeigniter/test.html let me clear one more thing olx is the folder name and the controller file name as well and is placed at the following location
D:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\controllers\olx\olx.php now what u suggest

Comment: one more thing if I want to remove codeigniter from the url as well like localhost/olx

Comment: I will be implementing the suggestions made by you tonight and will report you back!

Comment: yes it worked finally thanks alot davedrisemans that I want to clear
i have D:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\views\olx\frmSignup as my view when I load this view using my olx controller it says page not found if I access it via http://localhost/codeigniter/olx/frmSignup
further my route setting is 
$route['default_controller'] = 'olx';
$route['olx/frmSignup']  = 'olx/frmSignup';
one more thing I need to know for multiple CI application do I need to create separate folders and paste all my CI framework to new folder

Comment: remove $route['olx/frmSignup'] = 'olx/frmSignup';  there is no need for, create a frmSignup as function in your controller (just like the index on top) and then you get 'olx/frmSignup' as. then you can pass data to the view and get data from your model. but that's understanding the basics of an MVC framework, enjoy.

Comment: my olx controller
class Olx extends CI_Controller
{
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();
  $this -> load -> model('olx_model');
 }
 public function frmSignup()
 {
  $this -> load ->helper('form');
  $this -> load -> library('form_validation');
  
  $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
  $this -> form_validation -> set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
  
  if($this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE)
  {

   $this -> load -> view('olx/frmSignup');
  }
  else
  {

   echo "failed";
  }
  
 } 
}

Comment: I have fmrSignup function in my Olx controller and view at the location D:\xampp\htdocs\Codeigniter\application\views\olx\frmSignup still getting 404 but if i execute the code give by u for olx controller it works as there is no view attached to it just echo statement

Comment: @Mubbashir... i think my answer answered the above question... would be good to mark it like that

Answer (score 0):

after all said by friends, you have to do another thing (I think you are doing it on localhost):

First, double check the suggestions: 
then go to windows tray, right click on WAMP icon, and then click on it , go to Apache menu, and then to modules and then check for rewrite_module to see if it is checked or not, and click on it if you find it unchecked (means disabled) to enable it. Now try again and report it...

Comment: yes I've double checked all suggestions, working on localhost and using xampp not wamp and checked in loaded modules for mod_rewirte its there please suggest am stuck in this stupid problem

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create .htaccess file on the root application folder or edit it if you already have. The following .htaccess file works for me.

### .htaccess

```
# BEGIN ci
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```